# Looking for a nice, condensed, but readable font

Tags: font-recommendation

I'm working on designing some badges and am looking for a nice, condensed, but readable font.

I usually use Helvetica-Condensed, but for this project I need type that is smaller than 9pt. Helvetica has the disadvantages of very closed letters, very static, similar forms, and very tight spacing.

Does anyone have any recommendations for a free font I could use?

Also, maybe your favorite condensed fonts that look good at 7pt, 8pt and 9pt.

Thanks!

Comment: Screen or print?

Comment: It's for the web

Comment: 7pt condensed for the web? That's likely not going to work well regardless of the typeface.

Comment: Readability isn't primarily opinion-based - Helvetica has been known to struggle on the screen at smaller sizes. Some choices (like a typeface designed for the screen instead of print) will be objectively better.

Answer (score 1):

That's a relatively tall order.

Free fonts (at least the kinds you'd find on a site like Dafont) are often characterized by not having condensed or expanded variants and not doing extensive hinting work for smaller sizes.

That said, here are a few suggestions:

1. Calibri is not free, but it is relatively freely available, more narrow than your typical sans, and looks good on the screen. Might be worth a shot.
2. [Roboto Condensed](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto+Condensed) is Google/Android's ripoff of Helvetica, but it's a decent ripoff and it's made for the screen, particularly mobile screens.
3. [Open Sans Condensed](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans+Condensed) isn't bad, but it doesn't have a normal weight.
4. Go to [Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/) and either search for "condensed" or use the "Width" filter to get some different widths. Plug 'em in and see how they work for you!